Woocommerce plugin increasing Database size
My site is hosted on Hostinger, it's ecom site working on Woocommerce plugin. It is causing my Database increasing in every minute. I have run test on database using plugin to sweep old data also. But it's keep on increasing and reached database limit.
Hostinger has set limit for database when, It's reached all write operation revoked. In order to run again I have to optimize. But again within 6 hours limit reach.
I don't what's the solution which file should delete.
